# error EclipseLink-4021 when creating EntityManager at runtime why?

Tags: java, eclipselink

I am trying to create EntityManager at runtime so I can set different user name and password from a config.xml

Here is the code to to create the EntityManager

```
map.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_USER,  SystemConfig.getConfig().getString("jdbcUser"));
map.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_PASSWORD, SystemConfig.getConfig().getString("jdbcPassword"));
map.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_URL, SystemConfig.getConfig().getString("jdbcUrl"));
map.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_DRIVER, "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
EntityManager eMgr = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPU", map).createEntityManager();
```

My program structure in unix:
~/test/myProgram.jar
~/test/lib/*.jar (all library and jdbc.jar here)

The program works fine when I run the program inside the folder /test/
However when I run the program under the root ~/ I get the Exception [EclipseLink-4021].
Any idea why??

Note: Ultimately I need to schedule the program using cron job.

```
[EL Info]: 2013-05-06 12:10:18.989--ServerSession(1729331687)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2013-05-06 12:10:19.002--ServerSession(1729331687)--Exception [EclipseLink-4021] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Unable to acquire a connection from driver [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver], user [null] and URL [null].  Verify that you have set the expected driver class and URL.  Check your login, persistence.xml or sessions.xml resource.  The jdbc.driver property should be set to a class that is compatible with your database platform
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4021] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Unable to acquire a connection from driver [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver], user [null] and URL [null].  Verify that you have set the expected driver class and URL.  Check your login, persistence.xml or sessions.xml resource.  The jdbc.driver property should be set to a class that is compatible with your database platform
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:602)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:278)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:304)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:282)
        at dcsmailcheck.MailResend.<init>(MailResend.java:61)
        at dcsmailcheck.Main.main(Main.java:49)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4021] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Unable to acquire a connection from driver [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver], user [null] and URL [null].  Verify that you have set the expected driver class and URL.  Check your login, persistence.xml or sessions.xml resource.  The jdbc.driver property should be set to a class that is compatible with your database platform
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.unableToAcquireConnectionFromDriverException(DatabaseException.java:376)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:91)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:685)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:215)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:542)
        ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code works in folder ~/test, it seems that `SystemConfig.getConfig()` fails to load the properties from that place. Make sure that you have added the path to your properties to the CLASSPATH.

Comment: Yea thanks. It confuses me that in other occasion if SystemConfig.getConfig() have issue it gives an error that "jdbcUser" or whatever is not accessible or not exist etc. But when used in above situation it doesn't prompt that error and instead prompt an EclipseLink error...